# How do I verify that the expected array is the actual array in MSTest?

Tags: c#, mstest

The following method fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyArrays()
{
    int[] actualArray = { 1, 3, 7 };
    Assert.AreEqual(new int[] { 1, 3, 7 }, actualArray);
}
```

How do I make it pass without iterating over the collection?

Comment: Why did you post a question only to answer it with 1 minute of googling? Why post the question at all? Or is this more of a PSA?

Comment: Public Service Announcement... hmm...  Following the lead of Jeff Atwood on making SO the canonical place for questions and answers.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Microsoft has provided a helper class [`CollectionAssert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert(VS.80).aspx).

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyArrays()
{
    int[] actualArray = { 1, 3, 7 };
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[] { 1, 3, 7 }, actualArray);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyArrays()
{
    int[] actualArray = { 1, 3, 7 };
    int[] expectedArray = { 1, 3, 7 };

    Assert.IsTrue(actualArray.SequenceEqual(expectedArray));
}
```